# CISCO: ARP Poisoning Countermeasures

Tags: security, cisco, arp, cisco-catalyst, arp-poisoning

How can I prevent the Cisco Catalysts 2950/2960/3550/3750 from being vulnerable to ARP Poisoning?

Can this be avoided with the ARP INSPECTION?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in general on Cisco kit you'd use any or all of "DHCP Snooping", "Dynamic ARP Inspection (DAI)" or just plain port-security. Now I just need to lookup which of these are supported by your kit - back in a minute.

EDIT - Just checked all switches support all three features but you'll want to be on 12.1(22) at least.